# Rails rspec and omniauth (integration testing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, integration-testing, omniauth, rspec-rails

My Rails 3.2 app uses OmniAuth and Devise to sign in with Twitter. The authentication system works fine. I would like to write an integration test in rspec to make sure everything works. Using the information in the wiki, I've written the following, but I know I'm missing things.

Under test.rb in config/environments, I have the following lines

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] = {:provider => 'twitter', :uid => '123545'}
```

My rspec test looks like this:

```
describe "Authentications" do
  context "without signing into app" do

    it "twitter sign in button should lead to twitter authentication page" do
      visit root_path
      click_link "Sign in with Twitter"
      Authentication.last.uid.should == '123545'
    end

  end
end
```

Authentication is the name of my model and calling .uid in rails console returns the string fine.

I'm getting the following error when I run this test:

```
Failure/Error: Authentication.last.uid.should == '123545'
NoMethodError:
undefined method `uid' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to use the OmniAuth mocks that are provided? An explanation for *why* and *how* it works would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I run into something similar.

After changing my mock object from using symbol keys:

```
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] = {
    :uid => '1337',
    :provider => 'twitter',
    :info => {
      :name => 'JonnieHallman'
    }
  }
```

to using string keys:

```
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] = {
    'uid' => '1337',
    'provider' => 'twitter',
    'info' => {
      'name' => 'JonnieHallman'
    }
  }
```

it worked.

And do you have

```
  request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter]
```

somewhere in your testcase?

Comment: Hello! I tried request.env["omniauth.auth"], but i get error "undefined method env for nil class"

Answer (score 6):

Did you try moving these two lines to spec_helper.rb?

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] = {:provider => 'twitter', :uid => '123545'}
```

Also add the following before block in your test file:

```
before do 
    request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] 
end
```

You can find more info on this link: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing

Answer (score 4):

I highly suggest [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710660/rspec-simple-example-getting-error-on-request-variable-in-integration-test)

In short...

- Set up the mock
- Make the request
- Test whatever code is attached to the callback

For example: test the session['uid'] was set (although, I opt to test only what the user sees, or, rather, does not see)

My code...

*config/environments/test.rb*

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ...
    OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:linkedin] = { 
      'provider' => 'linkedin', 
      'uid' => '123545', 
      'info'=>
      { 'email'=>'infinite@jest.com',
        'first_name'=>'Dave',
        'last_name'=>'Wallace' }
    }
end
```

*spec/features/sign_in_feature_spec.rb*

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'Sign in with LinkedIn' do

  before do 
    OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:linkedin, {:uid => '12345'})
  end

  let(:user) { create(:user) } 

  scenario 'with valid email and password' do
    visit '/'
    expect(page).to have_no_content 'Sign Out'
    click_link 'nav-sign-in' # image/button: Sign in with LinkedIn
    expect(page).to have_content 'Sign Out'
  end
end
```

Let me know if/how I may improve this solution (and my code!)

Answer (score 3):

Selected solution does not work for me.
My solution i get from https://gist.github.com/kinopyo/1338738
and official doc https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing
here:

```
# in spec/support/omniauth_macros.rb
module OmniauthMacros
  def mock_auth_hash
    # The mock_auth configuration allows you to set per-provider (or default)
    # authentication hashes to return during integration testing.
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:odnoklassniki] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
         :provider => 'odnoklassniki',
         :uid => '123545',
         :info => OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash.new({
             :name => 'mockuser'
         })
     })

  end
end

# in spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|

  # email spec
  config.include(EmailSpec::Helpers)
  config.include(EmailSpec::Matchers)
end
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

# in spec example:
visit new_user_registration_path
mock_auth_hash
find('#btn-odnoklassniki').click # here is link generated as omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider)
```

Comment: thank you for pointing towards the AuthHash.new (although it is in the integration testing web page)i only managed to get this to work with koala if I have FactoryGirl of my authorisation model that included real secret and token  (e.g. copy and pasted from a valid facebook login transition)