# rspec simple example getting error on request variable in integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This is an adopted rails app with no tests. I am trying to test omniauth in an integration test but am getting an error (**edit** I have based upon this: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing). This reflects my lack of understanding of Rspec. It would seem that the request object would be available by default.

I have in my spec/spec_helper.rb:

```
config.include IntegrationSpecHelper, :type => :request
Capybara.default_host = 'http://localhost:3000'

OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook, {
  :uid => '12345'
})
```

and in my spec/integration/login_spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ServicesController, "OmniAuth" do
  before do
    puts OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook]
    puts request # comes back blank
    request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook]
  end

  it "sets a session variable to the OmniAuth auth hash" do
    request.env["omniauth.auth"][:uid].should == '12345'
  end
end
```

and I get the following error:

> {"provider"=>"facebook", "uid"=>"12345", "user_info"=>{"name"=>"Bob
>   Example"}}
>
> F
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) ServicesController OmniAuth sets a session variable to the
>   OmniAuth auth hash
>        Failure/Error: request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook]
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
>        # ./login_spec.rb:8:in`block (2 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 22.06 seconds 1 example, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./login_spec.rb:11 # ServicesController OmniAuth sets a session
>   variable to the OmniAuth auth hash

Should the request object be available here, by default? Does this error possibly mean something else?

thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting `nil` because you haven't made any request yet.

To make the test work, you have to do three things:

1. Set up the mock
2. Make the request
3. Test whatever code is attached to the callback

Here's how I do it. First set up the mock in the `before` block, and then visit the URL corresponding to the provider (in this case facebook):

```
before do
  OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook, {:uid => '12345'})
  visit '/auth/facebook'
end
```

From the [wiki](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing):

> A request to /auth/provider will redirect immediately to /auth/provider/callback.

So you have to have a route which matches '/auth/:provider/callback'. Whatever action you map that do has to perform the stuff in step 3 above.

If you wanted to test that the session variable was set to the uid, you could do something like this (which works because you set the uid to '12345' in the mock above):

```
it "sets a session variable to the OmniAuth auth hash" do
  session['uid'].should == '12345'
end
```

And here's a route and action that should make this pass:

routes.rb

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#callback'
```

controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
def callback
  session['uid'] = request.env["omniauth.auth"][:uid]
end
```

That's the gist of it. Hope that helps.